# Getting logged in user information (using Facebook Login) in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, userinfo

We're using Oauth (FB Social Sign on through 'Socialiser' plugin) to log users to our Wordpress site.
In order to gather analytics, we have to embed currently logged in user's email to an external hyper link.

A new user's profile is automatically created in wordpress(with their email address from Facebook) upon first login.

Based on wordpress documentation, I have added the following code to create a short code within functions.php:

```
function user_email($atts){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
return $current_user->user_email;
 }
add_shortcode('u_email','user_email');
```

Tried using the short code [u_email] in the post but it doesn't seem to contain any information about user's email.

Just wondering if I'm using the code correctly or it would just work on locally authenticated users only?

Is there's come other way to find the information related to logged in users ?

Thanks in advance!